# Geography union via cursor returning null

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, null

I need to combine multiple geography records into a single entity to store in a spatial data table, but I've learned that the only available function in MSSQL2008R2 that accomplishes this task is STUnion which only works for two static geography records. I have upwards of 200 that I need to union and I'm loathe to hand code that kind of query.

On that note, I wrote up a one-off cursor to iteratively union each geography object from my staging table. However, when executed, the cursor returns a null value without any errors or messages.

```
DECLARE
    @ShapeUnion GEOGRAPHY,
    @Shape GEOGRAPHY

DECLARE curSpatial CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    geom
FROM
    dbo.Boundaries_Staging

OPEN curSpatial

FETCH NEXT FROM curSpatial INTO @Shape

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @ShapeUnion = @ShapeUnion.STUnion(@Shape)

    FETCH NEXT FROM curSpatial INTO @Shape

END

CLOSE curSpatial
DEALLOCATE curSpatial

SELECT @ShapeUnion
```

---

**Edit**: Updated script for anyone curious about unioning multiple geography records. As stated in the comments, I initialized @ShapeUnion prior to the loop. Also, I added .STBuffer() to the field being unioned; this ensures that the miniscule spaces between the spatial data are completely filled.

```
DECLARE
    @ShapeUnion GEOGRAPHY,
    @Shape GEOGRAPHY

DECLARE curSpatial CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    geom
FROM
    dbo.Boundaries_Staging
WHERE
    geom IS NOT NULL

OPEN curSpatial

FETCH NEXT FROM curSpatial INTO @Shape

SET @ShapeUnion = @Shape

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @ShapeUnion = @ShapeUnion.STUnion(@Shape.STBuffer(1))

    FETCH NEXT FROM curSpatial INTO @Shape

END

CLOSE curSpatial
DEALLOCATE curSpatial


SELECT @ShapeUnion
```

Comment: You're entirely correct, I didn't even notice that. Worked fine when I initialized @ShapeUnion before the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try inside the loop:

```
SET @ShapeUnion = COALESCE(@ShapeUnion.STUnion(@Shape), @Shape);
```

(Or initializing `@ShapeUnion` somehow first.)

You'll also want to filter the cursor query to not include any rows where `geom` is `NULL` (if that is possible in your data model).

You can also do this without a cursor, I think:

```
DECLARE @ShapeUnion GEOGRAPHY;

SELECT @ShapeUnion = COALESCE(@ShapeUnion.STUnion(geom), geom) 
  FROM dbo.Boundaries_Staging
  -- WHERE geom IS NOT NULL
  ;

SELECT @ShapeUnion;
```